# Add Description to Document Library

Tags: office-365, document, library

Currently I'm creating a structure on our new SPO (SharePoint in Office 365).
Now, my boss wants a description in every folder above the content of the document library.

As it's not possible to add a content-editor webpart within a document library, I've tried a lot of things, but I wasn't able to find any solution. The only thing I found out is, that you can add a description to the little info sign on the rigt side of the document library name. But this info only appears with a mouseover, so it's not really visible for normal users.
By way of illustration, here a simple "example".
[image]

It would be very great, if you could help me with my problem.

Comment: thats an interesting requirement. so you want a description on top of every library generically? or for a specific library, customize each location's (folder) description? will this have to be dynamic or you can "hardcode" the description just for existing folders?

Comment: Will the description change per folder?  Or is the description the same throughout the library? If it changes per folder, you can consider Document Sets, which have a page that you can customize.

Comment: The whole "file structure" is placed in one Document library and the description should change per folder.
Please can you describe the thing with documents sets more precise?
Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm not an expert by any means, but a very rough 'work around' is to create a new page, add a text box, and then add the Document Library App in (but it won't show as many documents as the document library itself) :(.....

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @wjervis, doc sets are probably the way to go. You can edit your library, add the Document Set content type, and then add additional properties and such to the doc set.

A doc set is a folder juiced up with more functionality/properties. Here's a good start into them: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA101782461. Once setup, you'll want to edit the Welcome Page to include your description.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the page and add a webpart to the page where you can then add your description.  The only down side to doing this is that you will then loose your library tabs when first going to the page unless you click within the library on the page whenever you go to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Click "Edit Page" from the settings wheel in the top right corner of your document library, then click "insert Text". After you're finished entering your text, select "Stop Editing" under "Page" to save it.